# How to reduce the hidden width of span?

Tags: javascript, css, html

i am working on `tooltip`, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/22vGk/1/) is my code. When i move the mouse near question mark, it shows me the tooltip, How i can show the tooltip, only when i bring the mouse on question mark

Comment: you've tagged your question as javascript but your code does not contain any. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/22vGk/2/)

I added

```
width:0px;
overflow:hidden;
```

to the tooltipsignup before css

and then flip it to

```
width:186px;
overflow:visible;
```

on hover

Comment: @baig772 If you're going to do this I would at least make sure the hover state uses auto width, else you've given yourself a maintenance pain.

Comment: I only used 186px because that is what he had initially in his code. Although auto might give you a single line of text really wide, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't working because the span you've attached the hover effect to includes the tooltip, which is increasing the size of its parent because you've made it transparent rather than remove it from the flow.

The simplest solution would be to add display: none to .tooltipSignup and display:inline-block to .tooltipSignup:hover

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `opacity:0` and `opacity:1` use `display:none` and `display:block`

Comment: Then you won't get the nice transition though, right?

Comment: Just be aware that using display:none destroys css transitions like the one he is using on opacity.

Answer (score 0):

add this code. it is working great.

```
 <span class="hover">? 
                            <span class="tooltipSignup">
                               Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type 
                            </span> 
                        </span>
```

---

```
.hover {
    position:relative;
    top:2px;
    left:5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.tooltipSignup {
    width: 186px;
    
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
   
    position:absolute;
    display: none;
   
}

.hover:hover .tooltipSignup {
    display : block;
}

.hoverCupon {
    position:relative;
    top:3px;
    left:4px;
}

.tooltipCupon {
    width: 133px;
    top:-20px;
    right:-20px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -moz-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition:  opacity 0.5s;
    transition:  opacity 0.5s;
}

.hoverCupon:hover .tooltipCupon {
    opacity:1;
}
```